# JNA - passing the value behind a pointer, as value?

Tags: java, pointers, jna, pass-by-value

I'm not quite sure whether what I want to do actually makes sense, but I tried all other avenues without success.

The problem involves three C-functions, which I have to call from Java using JNA. 
The first expects a NULL-pointer, which it will allocate:

```
void allocate_func(mystruct *struc)
{
    //allocates *struc
}
```

The second expects the allocated pointer and writes to it:

```
void write_func(mystruct *struc)
{
    //writes something to struc
}
```

The third expects the same object but by value, and reads from it:

```
void read_func(mystruct struc, char** something)
{
    //writes data from struc to something
}
```

I'm experiencing some trouble in accommodating all of this. First of, if I pass a PointerType to alloc_func, I get a crash. If I pass a PointerType.getPointer(), the same happens. I figured the allocation happens "too close to home", upsetting the Java reference. So I passed a PointerByReference.getPointer() instead for an additional layer of dereferenciation, and that works. Well, at least it doesn't crash.

The function that writes stuff is the only that seems straightforward to me, create a PointerType from the PointerByReference and pass that. It builds and also doesn't crash, but so far I haven't been able to ascertain if anything is actually written.

The reason for this being, I am at a complete loss how I pass my PointerType by value to the third function to actually get the information I want.

Before this I tried making a class extending Structure, but while I got that working without crashing, I never got any data back in it either, so this is a second attempt.
I'm open to comments on what I did so far, on how to pass the value contained in a PointerType, or a completely different approach for solving the above described problems.

Here's what the code currently looks like:

The object:

```
public static class mystruct extends PointerType 
{
    public mystruct(Pointer address) {
        super(address);
    }
    public mystruct() {
        super();
    }
};
```

The bindings:

```
void allocate_func(Pointer info);
void write_func(mystruct info);
```

Note that currently I don't have a clue how I would bind read_func correctly, that's exactly the problem...

The code:

```
PointerByReference mystructptr = new PointerByReference();
allocate_func(mystructptr.getPointer());
mystruct struc = new GPPortInfo(portinfoptr.getValue());
write_func(struc);
```

Again, as mentioned, no idea how I can pass struc as value, so there's no code for that yet.

Comment: We'll need to see your Java code to in order to help you.

Comment: will post, but the truth is that for the actual problem, I have no code... I haven't managed to come up with any syntactical contraptions that built.

Comment: And also you should post the rest of your C code, at least the relevant parts. Are you sure the crash is caused by the JNA call? Couldn't it be a problem within your C code?

Comment: It's not my C code, it's an external library (libgphoto2 to be more precise, but I abstracted things here in order for it to be more easily understandable). Still, I can post the code of that function, yes:

Comment: int
gp_port_info_new (GPPortInfo *info) {
 C_MEM (*info = calloc (1, sizeof(struct _GPPortInfo)));
 return GP_OK;
}

Comment: Your allocation needs to _return_ a pointer to the allocated memory, from which you can initialize a `Structure` or just pass around, if necessary.  The function needs to either directly return the pointer, or take a `void**` as a parameter (JNA `PointerByReference` exists for this purpose).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming common C implementations:

```
void alloc(struct _mystruct **);
void write(struct _mystruct *);
void read(struct _mystruct, char** unknown); // no idea what you're trying to do here

// JNA functions
void alloc(PointerByReference p);
void write(MyStruct s);
void read(MyStruct.ByValue s, PointerByReference p);
```

For allocation you'd extract the pointer from `alloc` with `PointerByReference.getValue()` and use it to initialize an instance of `MyStruct`.

As for passing a `struct` by value:

```
public class MyStruct extends Structure {
    public static class ByValue extends MyStruct implements Structure.ByValue {}
}
```

Comment: So in other words, it's simply not possible if the allocating C-function doesn't expect a **. I was beginning to suspect as much. When thinking through it it's even very logical, since the pointer in the Java code remains unaffected by the allocation. Should have figured that out earlier.

Comment: The question then becomes, is there a way to allocate the pointer myself in Java?

Comment: You can certainly pass in a `struct*`; you simply create an instance of `MyStruct` and JNA takes care of the native memory allocation.  I don't know why you'd call the native method `alloc`, though, if it's the caller that has already allocated the memory.

Comment: Yeah, I'm slowly unraveling the confusion. So if I new a Structure in Java, then the pointer below it is initialised and the memory reserved, so no sense to use the C-function for allocation... Then, to pass it by value, I create a Structure.ByValue from its pointer and pass that... I remember trying something like that, but I'll give it another go now that I understand better what's going on.

Comment: Say, if the native struct has a member of type char*, and the place where that pointer points will be changed by the native function, as what do I have to declare the bloody thing in Java?

Comment: In short, use a `String` (if that's what it is) or a `Pointer` for a generic buffer or if you're not certain.  When JNA initializes a `Structure` from native memory, it will read a non-null pointer (`const char*`) and populate a Java `String` object in the `Structure` field.  The native memory remains unchanged.  On write, JNA allocates memory for a native `String` and populates the native pointer field; the memory will remain allocated until the `String` object gets GC'd (usually when the `Structure` is no longer referenced or the field value gets changed).

Comment: But that's just the problem... write_func(Structure*) will NOT write to the buffer of an initialised char* member of Structure. It will initialise the member. Using a String results in no data, using a byte[] results in garbage, using a PointerType results in a crash... I guess I'll just have write some C wrapper functions for that C-code.

Comment: If your structure has a `char[]` buffer field, it will be read or written, but that is different from a `const char*` field, which is just a pointer.  It's very bad practice to expect a process to write to a pointer field within a structure without a very specific contract about what's going to happen.  JNA will certainly _not_ write to the memory behind any pointer unless you explicitly tell it to, except for well-documented cases (`struct*`, namely).

Comment: Maybe you could more clearly identify in your question the expected/designed information flow of your native API.